# git branch - local or what?

Tags: git, github

I ran the following commands:

(we have a staging branch called "master_next")

(1) `git fetch origin`

(2) `git checkout -b origin/master_next`

now, when I run

(3) `git branch`

I see some weird stuff. Instead of seeing

```
master
master_next
```

I see

```
master
origin/master_next
```

why is the branch I just checked out preceded with "origin" - is it somehow different?

here is the exact results:

```
CACSVML-13295:smartconnect amills001c$ git fetch origin
From http://github.csv.comcast.com/Baymax/smartconnect
 * [new branch]      master_next -> origin/master_next
 * [new tag]         0.0.2      -> 0.0.2
 * [new tag]         0.0.3      -> 0.0.3
CACSVML-13295:smartconnect amills001c$ git checkout -b origin/master_next
Switched to a new branch 'origin/master_next'
CACSVML-13295:smartconnect amills001c$ git branch
  master
* origin/master_next    //wth?
```

can anyone explain why this happened and how origin/master_next might be different than plain-old master_next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was in this command:**

```
git checkout -b origin/master_next
```

This command created a new branch `origin/master_next` instead of checking out the branch `master_next` that was created remotely.

**What you should have done:**

1. `git fetch origin`
2. `git checkout master_next`
3. `git branch`

The `git checkout branch_name` command with `-b` creates a new branch `branch_name` and then checkouts to that branch.

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name #will create new branch and checkout to it
```

Comment: i see, if I were git I would not allow the "/" character in branch names...if this is indeed what it sounds like

Comment: git even allows us to create branches with multiple `/` characters. `git checkout -b ab/cd/ef/gh` will create and checkout to a new branch `ab/cd/ef/gh`.

Answer (score 2):

You likely meant to use the `-t` option.

- `git checkout -t origin/branchname`
  will create a new local branch at the commit, that `branchname` on the `origin` remote is pointing to. It will at the same time set up that new local branch to track the remote branch. This means that you will be able to pull from and push to it with your local branch.
- `git checkout -b branchname`
  will create a new local branch at the commit that you are currently at.

Comment: so presumably the -t option is short for "track"? Do you have a link in the docs that describes this?

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -b origin/master_next` creates a new branch. -b is used to make a new branch. Instead try `git checkout master_next`